# .Net Processing large files using Parallel.ForEach is not keeping order

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

i am writing a piece of vb.net code to process line by line for a large text file with 19 columns delimited by  Quote followed by comma and another quote (ie ",").  I split the line based on the delimiter value ( ","). Then i look for any extra double quote each column (col) still contain and log to a db table, if found.  I am able to process it, but the issue is the order is not maintained. I need to write to the database table  which row and column contain the delimited  char (for further processing).   It seems somehow the loop is not able to catch the order.

****for eg**** : if input file contain 10 rows and 19 cols each , and the invalid delimited char is found on last column (19th col) on row1 and  last col on row10 , the logging (WriteLogToDb(Path.GetFileName(FileAlign.Common.InputFileName), rownum, colnum,,,,,,,,,,,,) is happening like this :  row1  - print correctly.  But , instead of saying  10th row contains bad column value , the parallel.foreach loop says 5th row is having bad col at 19th position.  As far as column num is considered, that order seem to be correct.

What am i doing wrong here ? Any alternatives ?

**sample file -->**

"col1val"","col2val"",""","cccccc"","xxxxxx"","xxxx"","12334"","331"",35344535"","xxx"","WA"","50000"",""","03/01/2000"",""",""",""",""",""Lin1Col19"
row2-->
row3->
----etc
row9-->
"col1val"","col2val"",""","aaaa"","xxxxxx"","xxxx"","4242"","6464"",533535353"","xxx"","PA"","6446`enter code here`"",""","04/01/1967"",""",""",""",""",""Lin1Col19"

Here is the code sample.

```
Public Sub ValidateExtraDoubleQuotes(FileName As String)
    Dim InputFile As String = FileName
    Dim rownum As Integer = 0
    Dim colnum As Integer = 0
    Dim SplittedValues() As String
    Dim delimiter As String = ""","""   '/*ie delimiter is ","*/
    Dim QT As String = """"   'escape single doublequote by adding another
    Dim ExtraQTFound As Boolean = False
    Dim QTRowCount As Long = 0
    Dim messagesLockRow As New Object
    Dim messagesLockCol As New Object

    Try

        Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(InputFile), Sub(line As String)
                                                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                                                        SyncLock messagesLockRow
                                                            rownum += 1
                                                            '/*' remove first and last chars from each line for further processing(ie. extra double quotes) *
                                                            line = (line.Remove(0, 1)).Remove(line.Length - 2, 1)
                                                            SplittedValues = line.Split(New String() {delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                                            SyncLock messagesLockCol
                                                                For Each Str As String In SplittedValues
                                                                    colnum += 1
                                                                    If Str.Contains(QT) Then
                                                                        ExtraQTFound = True
                                                                        WriteLogToDb(Path.GetFileName(FileAlign.Common.InputFileName), rownum, colnum, False, "Extra Double Quotes for-->" & Str)
                                                                    End If
                                                                Next
                                                            End SyncLock
                                                            colnum = 0
                                                            ExtraQTFound = False
                                                        End SyncLock
                                                    End Sub)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.Write(String.Concat("Exception!!", ex.Message.ToString()))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Parallel.ForEach you are commanding your code to work multiple lines at once by allocating the work to different threads with their output being combined after execution finishes. You cannot guarantee order when doing so. You should only use parallelism when order does not matter or if you have your own way of reordering the data after execution.

As far as alternatives. You could do something such as read each line to an array THEN use a parallel.ForEach to do your processing work after you have the data in an object that could maintain order. At that point if there is an error then you could pass the error msg to an object along with the array index and have it write sequentially to the DB based on the array index after all processing has occurred: This link would show you how to work with array indexes inside parallel.foreach loops http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ParallelForEachIndex.aspx